# Next.js build gives: "Build error occurred TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'services')"

Tags: reactjs, next.js, deployment, build, aws-code-deploy

I'm working on a Next.js project using a template , when I want to build the project running npm run build ,a folder .next is created and it gives some building errors

Here is the error:

```
Build error occurred
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'services')
    at C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\st\code\master\visitor\.next\server\chunks\7556.js:3216:101
    at __webpack_require__.a (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\st\code\master\visitor\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:103:13)       
    at 83027 (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\st\code\master\visitor\.next\server\chunks\7556.js:3169:21)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\st\code\master\visitor\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
    at C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\st\code\master\visitor\.next\server\chunks\7556.js:3416:83
    at __webpack_require__.a (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\st\code\master\visitor\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:103:13)       
    at 83782 (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\st\code\master\visitor\.next\server\chunks\7556.js:3405:21)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\st\code\master\visitor\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
    at C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\st\code\master\visitor\.next\server\chunks\7556.js:2186:66
    at __webpack_require__.a (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\st\code\master\visitor\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:103:13) {     
  type: 'TypeError'
}
```

I try deleting the .next file but every time I run `npm run build` the folder was created again.